# mac safari vs iphone safari

Tags: jquery, iphone, macos, safari, svg

works on safari/firefox/chrome/opera for mac + pc. But not for safari iPhone. `"error occurred"` is the message which is better than nothing but not very helpful.
Is there a quick way to determine the cause of the problem? The website itself is svg + a lot of javascript/jquery. It also uses

```
eval()
```

which may also be the reason of failure.

Erroneous website is [here](http://www.iscriptdesign.com), and code is in svn on code.google.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the problem is with `google.load()`. Apparently on certain browsers, the order of includes might not be that you would expect, therefore your plugin and other code would fail to load/execute.

I suggest you use the direct link to the Google CDN for your scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Alternatively you can attach a function to `google.setOnLoadCallback()` and use jQuery's `$.getScript()` in there as discussed in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/6c41073ebd02a32c), but the above is a lot cleaner solution.